# Scaling analog sensor output (0.4V to 2.7V) to full dynamic of ADC (Vref 3.3V)

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, dac

I have a question regarding the scaling of analog sensor output signal.

The goal is to connect a [Sharp GP2Y0A02YK0F](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Infrared/gp2y0a02yk_e.pdf) distance sensor to a Raspberry Pi 3 B.
The sensor can be run off the 5V rail of the Raspi. The output voltage differential is specified as:

[image]

And this example for a distance measuring is given:

[image]

Accordingly I expect my output from the sensor to be DC voltages between ~0.4V and ~2.75V. Each value being held for at least the duration of one measurement and for as long as the measured distance doesn't change at maximum.

As a ADC I plan to use a [MCP3204](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf) (12-Bit, 4 Ch., SPI), with the 3.3V rail of the Raspi as Vref and as single sided power supply.

To make use of the full dynamic of the ADC I would like to scale the output of the sensor and remove the offset before feeding it into the ADC.

For the scaling itself I think a non-inverting op-amp circuit should suffice. When leaving a little headroom I would go for Va=3.2/2.75=1.16.

What I don't know how to tackle is the 0.4V offset. If my signal was AC I would go for a simple high pass before the op-amp, but with the signal possibly being DC for longer periods of time, I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your signal range is, as a percentage of the range of the ADC, 71.2%. In equivalent LSbs that is 2917 LSBs. That's equivalent to a hypothetical ADC that has 11.5 bits resolution.

So my first observation is why bother: -

Given that any ADC has a real range that can never be relied upon to be exactly 0 volts to Vref, I don't really see much of an advantage to what you propose.

But, say you used an op-amp that modified your signal to the range you believe you want, what errors are incurred in doing so? Are you going to use 0.1% resistors (10 bit accuracy) or maybe 0.01% resistors (a bit over 13 bit accuracy). Are you willing to pay for that accuracy?

Each resistor will incur an error and those errors can be assumed to accumulate. Plus, there is the error from the op-amp and it's inability to get within 10 mV to 50 mV of the supply range means you can never get the full 12 bits you desire.

So, do you stick with an 11.5 bit system or, do you design an op-amp (with significant cost for the resistors) that might give you 11.8 bits?

Or, do you go with a 14 bit ADC and forget about this silly talk of a level and gain shifter?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I wasn't aware of how little accuracy I would gain from level and gain shifting.

Comment: Good point. It also adds a redundancy useful for finding errors like objects in 0..15 cm range where the graph is inverted. Combined with a maximum target speed information it can distinguish between a far and a near moving object

Comment: And you only have even this level of accuracy if the noise of the sensor is low enough. It probably isn't. But you can also average to gain more bits...

Comment: Also considering that the color and size of the object will change the output of the sensor drastically, unless it is in a ridiculously controlled environment it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Andy had a good response to you regarding the potential accuracy loss regarding the addition of a scaling and offset circuit. But there are also several other factors that you need to consider:

1. There will be variation from sensor to sensor on what analogue voltage corresponds to what distance. The signal voltage range chart from the data sheet shows the typical characteristics for 25C at 5V. But unit to unit will vary both in range and offset so it is good to leave the extra A/D input range on the low and high side to allow for this variation.
2. This sensor of not going to be so accurate that it can present repeatable readings at the full range resolution even if you could scale and offset at zero error. Spreading the sensor's speced range of 150-20cm across the full A/D range of 4096 counts yields a value of 0.03cm if the sensor was linear. The fact that the sensor is non linear makes things worse than this at some points and repeatability will be way way worse so there is just no reason to try for full scale adjustment.
3. Surface reflectivity will play a huge role in what the sensor feeds back as to its analogue voltage for any given set of conditions. For this reason it is not useful the think of a sensor like this as an absolute measuring device and as such A/D readings that you achieve should not be used that way.

There are probably much better strategies to use a sensor like this in a relative measurement mode were you detect dynamic changes and not really worry about absolute accuracy. Make decisions on how the sensor readings change from sample to sample as opposed to what the readings were at some time in the past where you had tried to calibrate an absolute reference point set. There are also techniques where you can run time "calibrate" or "null" the A/D readings based upon some startup condition or position. Both of these really demand that you make sure to have A/D converter margin both above and below the normal expected input voltage range. twenty or thirty percent margin would not be far off base.